# Android Studio: Google Maps blank on build to a connected device

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2

I've run out of Google search juice for the moment.

My issue is that when I run my app from Android Studio to a connected device, my map is blank, except for the zoom controls and the Google logo at lower left.

However, if I generate an apk of that same project, and side-load it onto my phone, that map works just fine. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you "generate a signed apk"? If so, you put a key in there, with which you sign it. The Google Maps API key is bound to that key.

BUT if you build+run directly form android studio, it signs with a generic debug key, which of course doesn't fit with the API key, which is generated to match the key you gave it.

You can get another API key for that generic debug key by reading the sha1 thingy out of the logcat when running the app and it doesnt work, there should be an error somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Marlon. 

Yeah, the error I get is E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).

Great suggestion on the logcat. I'll give that approach a try right now.